# Detecting target architecture in OPAM build

Tags: build, ocaml, opam

When writing an OPAM package configuration file, I can specify the target platform in the `build` field, like so:

```
build: [
  ["./configure" "build-linux" {os = "linux"}
                 "build-macosx" {os = "darwin"}
                 "build-cygwin" {os = "cygwin"}]
]
```

Is there a way to do the same for target architecture, e.g. `["./configure" "build-linux-x64" {os = "linux" && arch = "x86_64"}]`? TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the list of variables using `ocaml config list`. It shows that the variable you are after is indeed `arch`:

```
% opam config var arch
x86_64
```

So, yes, you can do that. But note that the syntax will be `os = "linux" & arch = "x86_64"`.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that there was an easy way to get the list of these variables.